# importing module relative to current script (beyond top level)

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-import

I have a project `a` with several versions of `main#.py` so I organize them into a directory called `run`. I normally run project `a` from `./a` by calling `python run/main1.py`. Because `main1.py` involves imports beyond the top level package, I need to specify `sys.path.insert(0, "./")` in `main1.py`.

Now I've created project `b` which imports `main1.py` from `a`. From `b\main.py`, how do I get `main1.py` to import `a/utils.py` specifically?

Requirements:

1. Project `a` is a project I worked on long ago so I would like to make limited changes to just its headers. I would like `python run/main1.py` to work like it currently does.
2. I may move the projects between different computers so `main1.py` needs to import `utils.py` relative to itself. (ie. not importing with absolute path)
3. I would like the solution to be scalable. `b` will need to import modules from several other projects structured like `a`. I feel that expanding the system's PATH variable may just mess things up. Is there a neater solution?

My projects' files are as follows:

- a

  - run

    - main1.py
  - utils.py
- b

  - main.py
  - utils.py

in `a/run/main1.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "./")
from utils import hello    # Anyway to specify this to be ../utils.py ?
hello()
```

in `a/utils.py`:

```
def hello():
    print('hello from a')
```

in `b/main.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
from a.run import main1

import utils
utils.hello()
```

in `b/utils.py`:

```
def hello():
    print('hello from b')
```

This is the current result. I would like the first line to print 'hello from a':

```
>>> python run/main1.py:
hello from a
>>> cd ../b
>>> python run/main.py:
hello from b           (we want this to be "hello from a")
hello from b
```

Comment: Perhaps add a ```main.py``` in the root directory, and use this as the entry point. This way, the working directory is at the very top level and you can import all of the sub modules such as ```a, b etc...```

Comment: Or, you can try something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55911452/4180176

Comment: this seems much neater than sys.path hack. Thanks!!!